# Magento2: API with dynamic field in end point

Tags: magento2, api

I want to develop the API with dynamic field in end point so how can i do that?

```
/V1/customer/group/{groupId}/erp/{erpId}/list
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create module like this blog .

https://www.aurigait.com/how-to-create-custom-api-in-magento-2/

Comment: Please don't answer if you don't understand the question properly